# AngularJS infinite scrolling (ng-repeat) - removing top elements from the DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, infinite-scroll

I have an ng-repeat which loads thousands of records with some complexity that can have an height between 100px and 1200px. Needless to say the performance gets quite a hit.

[Infinite scrolling](https://sroze.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) module would work just fine in most cases until you hit an edge case where you've scrolled down close to the bottom and most of the elements have been loaded into the DOM, which brings me back to square one.

[Angular-vs-repeat](https://github.com/kamilkp/angular-vs-repeat) would be perfect for my case, but I haven't figured out how to compute each following element's height, since they're not fixed.

Which takes me back to Infinite scrolling. 
I assume if the top elements (above the viewport) would be replaced with an empty DIV with a computed height equal of their total height sum the performance wouldn't be a problem. While scrolling up would render them back into the dom and subtract the empty DIV's height.

Has anyone tackled this before? Any suggestions? Code snippets would be wonderful.

Comment: Hard to get you helped without any example. Cany you reproduce a simular case through codepen/... ?

Comment: I was looking at the same virtual scrolling technique myself but never really implemented it as that would be over-engineering. I was also having items of varying height so existing plugins would need to be amended. If we got to point where performance would be hit and I would need to implement virtual scrolling I would definitely take very close look at aforementioned directive + likely introduce additional features like keep 1.5 page of elements at top and bottom (people can hit Home and End keys) and current view items. Between them would be empty height adjusted dummy containers.

Comment: Checkout vs-repeat demo page, it has a demonstration using variable-sized elements http://kamilkp.github.io/angular-vs-repeat/#?tab=6

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` has a pretty steep performance drop off with long lists due to the overhead associated with its bindings. One performance-conscious library I'm particularly fond of is [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/), which conveniently has [an example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-row-height/#gsc.tab=0) with variable row heights. You might see if it would work for your purposes.

If nothing out there seems to fit your needs for this, you can always roll your own directive and handle the DOM manipulation yourself like the code snippet I threw together below. It doesn't cover everything you mentioned, but it includes infinite scrolling and removes old elements, replacing their height with an empty `<div>`, without using ng-repeat.

```js
angular.module('SuperList', [])
  .controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile',
    function($scope, $compile) {

      // Magic numbers
      var itemsPerLoad = 4;
      var thresholdPx = 1200;
      var removeThresholdPx = 1600;

      // Options to control your directive are cool
      $scope.listOptions = {
        items: [],
        renderer: renderer,
        threshold: thresholdPx,
        removeThreshold: removeThresholdPx,
        loadFn: loadNewItems
      };

      // This function creates a div for each item in our dataset whenever
      // it's called by the directive
      function renderer(item) {
        var itemElem = angular.element('<div></div');
        itemElem.css('height', item.height + 'px');
        itemElem.html(item.text);
        return itemElem;

        // If each row needs special angular behavior, you can compile it with
        // something like the following instead of returning basic html
        // return $compile(itemElem)($scope);
      }

      // This gets called by the directive when we need to populate more items
      function loadNewItems() {
        // Let's do it async like we're getting something from the server
        setTimeout(function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < itemsPerLoad; i++) {
            // Give each item random text and height
            $scope.listOptions.items.push({
              text: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, Infinity),
              height: Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 1100)
            });
          }
          // Call the refresh function to let the directive know we've loaded
          // We could, of course, use $watch in the directive and just make
          // sure a $digest gets called here, but doing it this way is much faster.
          $scope.listOptions.api.refresh();
        }, 500);

        // return true to let the directive know we're waiting on data, so don't
        // call this function again until that happens
        return true;
      }
    }
  ])
  .directive('itemList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        itemList: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var el = element[0];
        var emptySpace = angular.element('<div class="empty-space"></div>');
        element.append(emptySpace);

        // Keep a selection of previous elements so we can remove them
        // if the user scrolls far enough
        var prevElems = null;
        var prevHeight = 0;
        var nextElems = 0;
        var nextHeight = 0;

        // Options are defined above the directive to keep things modular
        var options = scope.itemList;

        // Keep track of how many rows we've rendered so we know where we left off
        var renderedRows = 0;

        var pendingLoad = false;

        // Add some API functions to let the calling scope interact
        // with the directive more effectively
        options.api = {
          refresh: refresh
        };

        element.on('scroll', checkScroll);

        // Perform the initial setup
        refresh();

        function refresh() {
          addRows();
          checkScroll();
        }

        // Adds any rows that haven't already been rendered. Note that the
        // directive does not process any removed items, so if that functionality
        // is needed you'll need to make changes to this directive
        function addRows() {
          nextElems = [];
          for (var i = renderedRows; i < options.items.length; i++) {
            var e = options.renderer(options.items[i]);
            nextElems.push(e[0])
            element.append(e);
            renderedRows++;
            pendingLoad = false;
          }
          nextElems = angular.element(nextElems);
          nextHeight = el.scrollHeight;

          // Do this for the first time to initialize
          if (!prevElems && nextElems.length) {
            prevElems = nextElems;
            prevHeight = nextHeight;
          }
        }

        function checkScroll() {
          // Only check if we need to load if there isn't already an async load pending
          if (!pendingLoad) {
            if ((el.scrollHeight - el.scrollTop - el.clientHeight) < options.threshold) {
              console.log('Loading new items!');
              pendingLoad = options.loadFn();

              // If we're not waiting for an async event, render the new rows
              if (!pendingLoad) {
                addRows();
              }
            }
          }
          // if we're past the remove threshld, remove all previous elements and replace 
          // lengthen the empty space div to fill the space they occupied
          if (options.removeThreshold && el.scrollTop > prevHeight + options.removeThreshold) {
            console.log('Removing previous elements');
            prevElems.remove();
            emptySpace.css('height', prevHeight + 'px');

            // Stage the next elements for removal
            prevElems = nextElems;
            prevHeight = nextHeight;
          }
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.item-list {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.item-list > div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item-list > .empty-space {
  background: #aaffaa;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
</head>

<body ng-app="SuperList" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <div class="item-list" item-list="listOptions"></div>

  <script src="https://opensource.keycdn.com/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How would you solve/add back items if you scroll backwards?